# React pass props to children edge case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My app has the structure below and I would like to pass a prop based in the Header state to the RT component. I can pass it easily with Context but I need to call an API when the prop is a certain value and Context doesn't seem to be designed for this use due to it using the render pattern.

In Header.js I render the children with `this.props.children`. To pass props I've tried the following patterns but nothing is working. I'm missing a concept here. What is it?

```
(1) React.Children.map(children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, { doSomething: this.doSomething }));

(2) {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { loggedIn: this.state.loggedIn })}

(3) <Route
      path="/issues"
      render={({ staticContext, ...props }) => <RT {...props} />}
    />
```

Structure:

App.js

```
<Header>
  <Main />
</Header>
```

Main.js

```
const Main = () => (
  <Grid item xl={10} lg={10}>
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={RT} />
        <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
        <Route path="/issues" component={RT}/>
        <Route path="/notes" component={Notes} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  </Grid>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend using the React Context API to handle the user state rather than manually passing it via props. Here's an example of how I use it:

```js
import React from 'react';

export const UserContext = React.createContext();

export class UserProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: false,
            onLogin: this.login,
            onLogout: this.logout,
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const user = getCurrentUser(); // pseudo code, fetch the current user session
        this.setState({user})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <UserContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </UserContext.Provider>
        )
    }

    login = () => {
        const user = logUserIn(); // pseudo code, log the user in
        this.setState({user})
    }

    logout = () => {
        // handle logout
        this.setState({user: false});
    }
}
```

Then you can use the User context wherever you need it like this:

```js
<UserContext.Consumer>
    {({user}) => (
        // do something with the user state
    )}
</UserContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to call an API based on the Context value and you can't do that with context because it is using the render pattern.

Comment: I do the same thing, using firebase authentication. You have access to all of the same lifecycle events as components. if you need to access context as props you can create a higher order component that passes the context, like this: https://github.com/forrestLyman/dig-framework/blob/master/src/lib/core/withDig/withDig.jsx

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising, I'll give it a try.